# How do I attach Javadocs for a Gradle dependency in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, gradle

My Gradle project is pulling in some jar dependencies from file like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '*.jar')
}
```

I have downloaded the Javadocs for one of the dependencies as a zip file, how do I add the Javadocs in Eclipse?

When I right click on the Gradle dependency and try to add Javadocs I see this:

> The current class path entry belongs to container 'Gradle Dependencies (persisted)' which does not allow user modifications to Javadoc locations on its entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the javadoc zip via `eclipse` closure. It could be achieved using the following code by

```
eclipse {
    classpath {
        file {
            whenMerged { cp ->
                // Add sources to a classpath entry
                def fileReferenceFactory = new org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.internal.FileReferenceFactory()

                def entry = cp.entries.find{ entry -> entry.path.endsWith('$YOUR_JAR.jar') }
                // add javadoc jar
                entry.javadocPath = fileReferenceFactory.fromPath(file('$JAVADOC_FOLDER/$JAVADOC_FILE.zip'))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Btw. I would suggest to add the a `*-sources.jar` as this also makes the javadoc hints available if it is possible. This can be done using the above code and

```
// add sources jar
entry.sourcePath = fileReferenceFactory.fromPath(file('$SOURCES_FOLDER/$SOURCE_FILE.jar')
```

instead of `entry.javadocPath`.

Comment: I had to add `toString()` to `entry.javadocPath = fileReferenceFactory.fromPath(file('$JAVADOC_FOLDER/$JAVADOC_FILE.zip').toString())`. After doing that, something kept stripping out the `C:` from the absolute path to the javadoc file. I ended up building the sources into the jar and using that as the dependency.

Comment: Is there a better way for Eclipse 2019? By attaching javadoc without source, can method parameter names be shown in java editor instead of arg0,arg1?

Comment: does this apply if uisng eclipse gradle plugin? i.e  import project -> Gradle project

Answer (score 4):

It may be a bit complicated for a file jar. But if you are able to get the dependency from repo, then this is the way to go:

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  compile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
}

eclipse.classpath.downloadJavadoc = true
eclipse.classpath.downloadSources = false
```

After I do `gradle cleanEclipse eclipse` I get something like that in `.classpath`:

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/.../javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar">
  <attributes>
    <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="jar:file:/C:/.../javax.servlet-api-3.1.0-javadoc.jar!/"/>
    <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
  </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

Comment: where is the javadoc.jar gradle expected?

Comment: You just add those two lines as the end of the `build.gradle`?

Comment: Yes, you may say so.